# Issue whe starting Apache with Xampp

Tags: windows, apache, xampp

Hello everone hope you can help me with this issue: I'm trying to start my apache using Xampp and heres the error it thows:

```
14:25:46  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
14:25:46  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
14:25:46  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
14:25:46  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
14:25:46  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
14:25:46  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
14:25:46  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

I tryed changing the ports in the .conf files with no luck, I believe because my computer did restart unexpectedly so this might be the reason why it doesn't start. I tryed that and I'm now looking for some clues on what to do to solve this problem, again hope you can help me out on this one.

I'm running Xampp v3.2.1 on Windows 7 home edition

Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue, it seemed that there was an issue with Skype, not so sure thought but I restarted the machine, closed Skype, and it worked.